# How do i write ajax json call in angular,here is my working js function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, angular

On a button click i call this function below, what it does is, it calls a json , if it gets a success message then it stores the data it received. I am attaching below a screenshot of what exactly it is returning. Please note my js function works perfectly fine, i am starting new in angular and want to achieve the same in it.

```js
function check_1(){
 
     user_form_value= $("#user").val();
     password_form_value= $("#password").val();
    
 
     var dict = { username: user_form_value, password: password_form_value };

 $.ajax({
    url: 'http://funiks.com/adminv7/offline-api/login.php',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify(dict),
})
.done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
 if(data.status=="SUCCESS") {
    localStorage.setItem("getLoggedInUser",JSON.stringify(data.user));
    console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("getLoggedInUser")));
 
 
 loggeduser_array  = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("getLoggedInUser"));
 console.log(loggeduser_array.username);
 login_true_2();
 
 }
 //console.log
}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
 login_true_2();
}); 

    }
```

Here is what you get on success:[image]

I am getting started with angular, and on a button click `login.component.ts` is showing me this in console

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpModule  } from '@angular/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})

@Injectable()
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
user_form_value = "info@lamchemical.com";
 password_form_value = "lam";

  constructor() { }

  login(){
    console.log(this.user_form_value);
    console.log(this.password_form_value);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Please guide me how should i further go with `.axaj` and `.do` functions in angular. I wish to do exactly similar, if user exists / **if success** then i want to store the data in local storage.

You can just update my **login function** and guide me how to proceed on this.

Answer (score 0):

AngularJs has this pretty neat $http service for that:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http or in https://angular.io

Answer (score 0):

I would create a login service and put something like this in it:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class LoginService {
  constructor (
    private http: Http
  ) {}

  login(username: String, password: String) {
    return this.http.post('http://funiks.com/adminv7/offline-api/login.php', {username, password})
    .map((res:Response) => res.json());
  }

}
```

You import `http` and then call the `post` method. First parameter is the URL, second is the body, the third would be request options if there are any.

And then import this service into your component, and call login and subscribe to the results. I also don't believe that your component should have an `@Injectable` decorator above it....

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpModule  } from '@angular/http';
import { LoginService } from './login.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})

export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
   public user_form_value = "info@lamchemical.com";
   public password_form_value = "lam";

  constructor(private _loginService: LoginService) { }

  login(){
    console.log(this.user_form_value);
    console.log(this.password_form_value);
    this._loginService.login(this.user_form_value, this.password_form_value).subscribe(res => console.log(res))
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

So you call into the service's login method, pass through your username and password, and then subscribe and wait for the result. It would probably be good to have a `.catch` method on the service after the `.map` so that you can catch any errors that get thrown.

Comment: i do understand that i should have a different file and i should name it login.service.ts , as i am new, can i try to do this on login.component.ts just for the sake of better understanding and in next step i can do the actual suggested way ?

Comment: Yes, you can put it all in login component if you want. just create another method that does exactly what the login method does in the service and call it from the component.

Comment: i am trying as you are guiding, but facing errors see my login.components.ts code here line 27 - https://pastebin.com/dFbHx3BM

Comment: You need to take off @Injectable from your component. That is only used for services. Secondly, you need to install `map`. You're importing it but probably don't have it installed. You can install `rxjs` by running `npm install rxjs --save`

Comment: I installed as guided by you, i also took off @Injectables , but still it is showing some error - https://www.dropbox.com/s/vvqosuwz2bu29ml/Screenshot%202017-05-23%2009.26.55.png?dl=0

Comment: Yes, if you look at the line before the `.map` you have a semicolon, so javascript will interpret the statement as being terminated. You need to use the code that I gave you. Remove the semicolon, and the `.map` error will go away.

Comment: The problem is still there - have a look - https://www.dropbox.com/s/360vw1zh63657z9/Screenshot%202017-05-23%2014.22.57.png?dl=0

Comment: Like I said, you just need to copy and paste the code that I have. The issue is now an unexpected token, because it doesn't look like your method has a closing `}`. Go and read the documentation on angular's website https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html

Answer (score 0):

Use AngularJS's [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) service for that then.

```
 $http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: yourDesiredURL,
    data: yourData,
    headers: {
       'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
 }).then(function (response){
    // success
    console.log(response);
 }, function (response){
    // catch the error 
    console.warn(response);
 });
```

Comment: how do i call `data: yourData` , if you see my example in js i am doing it like this - ` var dict = { username: user_form_value, password: password_form_value };`  , how do i do it here

Comment: you'll have to serialize your data first since your data is an object, you can use jQuery's `$.param` for that. So in your case, it will be `data: $.param(dict)`  and that will return a serialized string in this format `username=user_form_value&password=password_form_value`. 
There are also a lot of available workarounds where you can pass an object as your data on an `$http` request. But that would be another story.

Comment: can you please correct my pastebin - https://pastebin.com/fpHPwVKk , getting following errors ,see screenshot here - https://www.dropbox.com/s/r24vlefybsv3bn0/Screenshot%202017-05-23%2014.46.38.png?dl=0